# Displaying image in the same JSP page

Tags: javascript, java, image, jsp

I have a problem with the folling JSP

```
    <h2>Click on filename to download or Click on 'Display' link to display content</h2>
    <div id="filelist">
    <%List<String> filenames = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("filenames"); 
    if(filenames.size()>0){
        for (String filenme : filenames){       
    %>
    <div id="filename">
        <a href="javascript:submit('<%=filenme%>', 'false')" onclick="javascript:submit('<%=filenme%>', 'false')"><%=filenme%></a>  
        <div id="displink"><a href="javascript:displayContent('<%=filenme%>', 'true')" onclick="javascript:displayContent('<%=filenme%>', 'true')">Display</a></div>            
    </div><br>
    <%  }
    }%>
    </div>
    <div id="displayContent">
    </div>
```

This will look like :  [Output of above code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibOZx.png)

When I click on the Display link, it is mapped to a servlet which gets the image with the filename sent and writes `BufferedImage` to `OutputStream` as shown below:

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(fs.open(item.getPath()));
if (isDisplay) {
    resp.setContentType("image/"+extn);
     ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bi, extn, bas);
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] byteArray=bas.toByteArray();
    String encdImgStr = Base64.encode(byteArray); 
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.write(encdImgStr);
```

My AJAX code is :

```
function displayContent(filename, isDisplay){
var ajaxRequest = getAjaxRequest();
document.getElementById("filename").value = filename;   
document.getElementById("isDisplay").value = isDisplay;

 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

      if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
         var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('displayContent');
         ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = "<img src=\"data:image/<%=request.getAttribute(\"extn\")%>;base64," + ajaxRequest.responseText + "/>";
         document.getElementById('displayContent').style.display="block";
      }
   }
 var parameters = "filename="+filename+"&isDisplay="+isDisplay;
 ajaxRequest.open("POST", "display", true);
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 ajaxRequest.send(parameters);
}
```

I am getting the string itself displayed in the output.
[Output of ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA6Sc.png)

Comment: User AJAX call instead of submit, so that you can do in same page instead of redirecting to new page. If you are using any JS Framework like JQuery, AJAX will be very easy.

Comment: Put an `img` tag in your same page, and update the `src` attribute to the servlet `url-mapping` with the file name.

Comment: I tried to make an ajax call as you suggested: in the servlet i am sending a base64 encoded string and trying to display in a img tag in jsp. in ajax i am creating the img tag when i get the response string . but the loop is stuck at ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 . the ready state value is always 3. I have edited my post and given the ajax code and servlet code. -

Comment: @Aravind :  can i do this putting 'img' tag even if my servlet is handling only Post requests. I need to pass filename and a boolean value to the servlet.